# How to get autocompletion with ">|"?

Tags: 12.04, command-line, bash, auto-completion

When trying to empty a text file with `>| filename` why doesn't bash's autocomplete work for the file name? Is there anyway to allow autocompletion like any other terminal command?

Comment: Works in `zsh` --- maybe bash autocompletion is expecting a command after "|"? (wild guess)

Comment: I rarely use this form, I don't run with `noclobber`, but I see this also. This might be a bug in the `bash-completion` package.

Answer (score 0):

When <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work, you can always try <kbd>Alt+/</kbd>, or whatever else bound to `complete-filename`.